# Deducing the Upper Limit for which the Integral is Zero

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

> Find all values of $c$ for which $\int_0^c |x(1-x)| dx = 0$.

I was reading [this](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/07/25/find-an-interval-of-integration-to-make-some-integral-equations-true/) solution, but to my mind it seems to be an invalid proof, though I cannot pinpoint exactly what is the problem. Here is the relevant part:

> Here, since $\left| x(1-x) \right| \geq 0$ for all $x$, we can use the comparison theorem (Theorem 1.20 in Apostol) to see that if $\left| x(1-x) \right| > 0$ for any $x$ then,
>   $$\int_0^c \left| x(1-x) \right| \, dx > \int_0^c 0 \, dx = 0.$$
>   So, for the equation to hold we must have
>   $$\left|x(1-x) \right| = 0 \quad \text{for all } 0 \leq x \leq c.$$
>   Since the expression will be nonzero for any 0 < x < 1, we must have c = 0.

It seems that the person who wrote the solution is not considering all values of $c$, only those greater than $0$. Moreover, it isn't true that $|x(1-x)| > 0$ over $[0,c]$ (the interval over which the author is integrating) and so the comparison test does not imply that $\int_0^c |x(1-x)|dx > 0$.

The author seems to be implicitly assuming the following: If $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is zero on one or both of the endpoints but strictly positive on $(a,b)$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx > 0$, but I don't believe this has been proven in Apostol's Calculus yet.

From what I understand, we begin by supposing that we have a $c \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\int_{0}^c |x(1-x)| dx = 0$, and then we want to deduce the specific value of $c$; and to me it seems that we have to consider cases, such that $c \in [0,1]$, $c \in (1,\infty)$, and $c \in (-\infty, 0)$, but that is somewhat annoying. Perhaps there is a simpler way; perhaps it would be better to prove that implicit assumption, since in that case we could use the comparison test for integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $\int_0^c |x(1-x)| dx = 0$ for $c=0$.

Now suppose that $c>0, c \le 1$ and $\int_0^c |x(1-x)| dx = 0$ . Let $f(t)=|t(1-t)|$ and $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$.

Hence $F(c)=F(0)=0$. By the mean value theorem, there is $a \in (0,c)$ such that

$0=F(c)-F(0)=F'(a)c=f(a)c$. Since $0<a<1$ we have $f(a) \ne 0$, thus $ c=0$, a contradiction.

For $c>1$ we have $\int_0^c f(t) dt \ge \int_0^1 f(t) dt>0$.

If $c<0$, then $\int_0^c f(t) dt=-\int_c^0 f(t) dt$ and we can show as above that $\int_0^c f(t) dt \ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

If $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is zero on one or both of the endpoints but strictly positive on $(a,b)$, then for every $\epsilon >0$ $$\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon} f(x)dx > 0$$
while
$$\int_a^{a+\epsilon} f(x)dx \geq 0$$
and
$$\int_{b-\epsilon}^{b} f(x)dx \geq 0$$
so
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx > 0$$